# No control panel equivalent of exim /etc/mailips file for configuring IPs for each domain's outgoing mail?

Tags: centos, smtp, exim

I have a problem with outgoing SMTP mail being sent with the wrong IP address.

I use exim for outgoing mail. I found [a guide](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Configure+Exim's+Outgoing+IP+Address) "How to manually configure Exim's outgoing IP addresses", which suggests modifying `/etc/mailips`. This file looks like exactly what I'm looking for.

Unfortunately the file doesn't exist on my server. On closer examination, I believe that file is not part of normal exim configuration but is created by a certain proprietary control panel package to ease configuring exim. I can't find any direct equivalent in exim.

How can I configure the IP address for outgoing mail for each domain in exim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that file is indeed something created by a certain proprietary control panel package.

The good news is, it's easy to roll your own. Exim config can fix an IP address with the `interface` property. In theory, it's one IP per server, but a little code can make it dynamic.

This is adapted from a [loginroot article](https://loginroot.com/how-to-sending-emails-using-user-assigned-ip-in-exim-directadmin/):

1. Find your exim config file, `exim.conf`. They suggest `/etc/exim.conf`, mine was in `/etc/exim/exim.conf`
2. Create a file to store domain - IP associations. I went with `/etc/exim/domainips`, they favoured `/etc/virtual/domainips`
3. Fill it with domains and IPs like this:

---

```
some-domain.com: 123.123.123.123
anotherdomain.org: 98.98.98.98
```

---

3. In the `exim.conf` file, find the section `remote_smtp:`
4. If there's an `interface = some.ip.add.ress` line below `remote_smtp:`, remove it.
5. Add a line using the file name from before:

---

```
  interface = "${lookup{$sender_address_domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domainips}{$value}}
```

---

6. Restart exim. `service exim restart` worked for me (Centos), or an alternative is `/etc/init.d/exim restart`

This then grabs the IP from the file for each email as it's sent, based on the sender domain.

---

*Note: as well as working in control-panel-free systems, this also appears to work with Vesta CP*