# How to have exim on server with multiple domains send each mail from its own domain, not the server hostname?

Tags: smtp, exim

Suppose I have a VPS with multiple dedicated IP addresses and multiple domains:

- `domain-a.com` is on `11.11.11.11`, mx is `mail.domain-a.com`
- `domain-b.com` is on `22.22.22.22`, mx is `mail.domain-b.com`
- `domain-c.com` is on `33.33.33.33`, mx is `mail.domain-c.com`

`domain-a.com` is the primary domain and the server's hostname is `server.domain-a.com`

Everything seems to be fine until I find that SMTP emails sent using Exim 4.72 are bouncing, failing or being flagged as spam to many domains. After some digging, I discover that there are mismatches: for emails from every domain, the `HELO` is from `server.domain-a.com`.

---

For example, I see this in headers on emails I send to gmail:

```
Received: from server.domain-a.com (mail.domain-c.com. [33.33.33.33])
```

And a mail testing service like https://www.mail-tester.com/ tells me:

> ### Your reverse DNS does not match with your sending domain.
>
> Your IP address 33.33.33.33 is associated with the domain mail.domain-c.com.
>
> Nevertheless your message appears to be sent from server.domain-a.com.
>
> You may want to change your pointer (PTR type) DNS record and the host name of your server to the same value.
>
> Here are the tested values for this check:
>
> ```
> IP: 33.33.33.33
> HELO: server.domain-a.com
> rDNS: mail.domain-c.com
> ```

But obviously I can't point `server.domain-a.com` at domains a, b and c at once, and anyway, I don't necessarily want domain-c.com to be sending via domain-a.com - let's assume they're independent businesses that just happen to be hosted on the same server.

How can I configure exim to send each email from its own domain, and to `HELO` from the mail server domain, not the server's primary hostname?

So that the headers look like this:

```
Received: from mail.domain-c.com (mail.domain-c.com. [33.33.33.33])
```

And the testing results report this:

> ```
> IP: 33.33.33.33
> HELO: mail.domain-c.com
> rDNS: mail.domain-c.com
> ```

---

[I found a solution to this same question for IP addresses](https://serverfault.com/questions/742013/no-control-panel-equivalent-of-exim-etc-mailips-file-for-configuring-ips-for-ea/742021#742021), which is how I'm sending mail from different IPs, so I'm sure there must be a similar solution for domains.

In my research all I could find was [this solution](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/question-about-mail-headers-hostname-and-ip.160174/) but it depends on cP***l and W*M and a file `/etc/mailhelo` that only exists in cP***l. It's clearly possible, but that solution depends on some behind the scenes gubbins baked into cP***l, which I don't use.

---

Operating system is CentOS if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was easier than expected.

I noticed my exim settings file (`/etc/exim/exim.conf`) contained this commented out line:

```
#helo_data = $sender_address_domain
```

Uncommenting it out caused the HELO / from to become the right domain, just missing the `mail.` prefix.

---

**So what worked for me was:**

**(1)** Under `remote_smtp:` in my exim config file, which on my system was located at `/etc/exim/exim.conf`, adding the following line:

```
helo_data = "mail.${sender_address_domain}"
```

**(2)** Restarting exim (on my system, that was `service exim restart`)

**(3)** That's all

---

After making this change, services like Mail Tester find no problems, and this section of my mail headers look normal:

```
Received: from mail.domain-c.com (mail.domain-c.com. [33.33.33.33])
```

The hostname does still appear later on in the email headers; [I've asked a separate question about that](https://serverfault.com/questions/759695/meaning-of-server-hostname-domain-appearing-in-exim-email-headers-sent-from-a-di).